# Intel xdk 2366 not installing on windows 10

Tags: windows, intel-xdk

Can anyone tell me what to do. I'm trying to install XDK 2366 on windows 10. When i click the xdk_web_master_2366.exe file it says Installing Intel XDK then after 5-10 seconds it just disappears and the installation stops. No error message. I've tried to turn off the firewall and disable windows defender but still facing the same problem. If anyone can assist i would greatly appreciate it.. Thanx

Comment: This is not a progrmamming question so would be better in the super user exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the instructions [on this Intel XDK forum post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/542074) for doing a complete uninstall, in case you have a partial install that is getting in the way. Do everything up to the "finally" step. Those instructions were written for people that wanted to stay with a previous version of the XDK.

Do not install that older version that is posted in that thread, it will be obsolete very soon.